# How to build in tree Linux kernel module in Yocto

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto

I am building a custom Linux kernel module using Yocto Project.

I have built successfully out of tree kernel module `custom_lkm.ko` and install it via `insmod`.

But I have no idea how to build it in tree module.

I am new and I am learning Linux from basic. Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/3.2.4/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a kernel module in tree, you need to understand the `Kbuild system`,

Each kernel module is a component/feature and it is called a `symbol`

Kbuild is based on four components:

- Configuration symbols (`CONFIG_EXAMPLE`)
- Symbols container (`Kconfig`)
- `Makefile`(s)
- The kernel main configuration file (`.config`)

So, if you want to add your module to the kernel tree you need to:

1. Copy the driver source file to the right location (You need to locate it based on your driver type (net, i2c, ...)).
2. Add a symbol entry for the driver in the Kconfig/Makefile files of the same driver source code directory.
3. Create a patch.
4. Activate the driver symbol in the main Kernel configuration file (menuconfig / config fragement)

### Example:

1. Get the workding directory of your kernel recipe:

```bash
bitbake -e virtual/kernel | grep ^WORKDIR=
```

2. Inside that directory you will find `git` which contains the kernel source, make your modifications there.
3. Add the driver source file:

```bash
cp /home/xxx/custom_lkm.c drivers/gpu/drm/panel
```

4. Add entry to Kconfig (`drivers/gpu/panel/Kconfig`)

```bash
...

config CUSTOM_LKM
    tristate "Example driver"
    depends on <YOU NEED TO FIND OUT WHAT IT DEPENDS ON>
    depends on DRM <-------( This is just an example of a panel driver )
    help
      Say Y if you want to enable support for Example driver.

...
```

5. Add entry to Makefile (`drivers/gpu/panel/Makefile`)

```bash
...
obj-$(CONFIG_CUSTOM_LKM) += custom_lkm.o
                   ^                ^
                   |                |
Driver symbol      |                |
in Kconfig----------                |
                                    |
Driver source file name -------------
...
```

6. Create a patch:

```bash
<workdir>/git$ git add drivers/gpu/panel/custom_lkm.c
<workdir>/git$ git add drivers/gpu/panel/Makefile
<workdir>/git$ git add drivers/gpu/panel/Kconfig
<workdir>/git$ git commit -m "Add the driver xxx in tree"
<workdir>/git$ git format-patch -1 -o /path/to/your/meta/recipes-kernel/linux/files

(This will create a patch: `add-the-driver-xxx-in-tree.patch`)
```

If your kernel is fetched from a local compressed file (no git), you then:

6.1 Init the kernel workdir as a git folder (git init)

6.2 Add and commit all the kernel (git add . && git commit -m "first init")

6.3 Add the driver files

6.4 Git add and commit and create the patch

Now, you got a patch that adds your driver in tree.

7. Add the patch to the `SRC_URI`. If you have a `bbappend` for the kernel you use just :

```bash
SRC_URI_append = " file://add-the-driver-xxx-in-tree.patch"
```

You need just to create a configuration fragment to activate it.

8. Run

```bash
bitbake virtual/kernel -c menuconfig
```

9. Activate your module
10. Create a configuration fragment

```bash
bitbake virtual/kernel -c diffconfig
```

This will generate a path to a `fragment.cfg` file. Just copy it along side the patch, and add it to `SRC_URI`.

## IMPORTANT NOTES:

- Make sure that your kernel can handle the `.cfg` files.
- If you have a custom kernel hosted in custom git (that you have access to) you just commit the driver changes to it and just update `SRCREV` and keep only the fragment part.